# refresh the page without redirecting

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a search form like this in a file form.php. It works great, the problem I am facing is that I use class/methods(functions). For example I have this method that calls logo and manu bar.

```
     //$this->output is just a method that echos, that's all it does

        function header()
        {
            $this->output('<DIV CLASS="header">');
            $this->logo();
            include('form.php');
            $this->links();
            $this->header_clear();
            $this->output('</DIV>');
        }
```

Like the above, the form shows perfectly, but when I choose a category it takes me to form.php, and it ruins everything. (form.php is just a form)

I know the problem is here

```
      onChange="javascript:this.form.action='form.php'; 
        this.form.submit()
```

Without javascript I couldn't get the category values, the page is not refreshing, so $_POST['cat'] is empty.

What is a better way to refresh the page without taking me to different one?

I know probably this all confusing, just bear with me.

```
     <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" id="form" action="form.php"    
        method="get">
     <SELECT name="cat"   onChange="javascript:this.form.action='form.php'; 
        this.form.submit()">
     <option value="" >Categories</option>

     <?php

   $z = "0" ;

    //Select categories form database

   $category =db_select_categories($z);
    if(is_array($category))
    {
    foreach($category as $rowc)
    {
    $id_cat = htmlentities($rowc['id_cat'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $cat_name = htmlentities($rowc['cat_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
    $cat_name = stripslashes($cat_name);
    echo "<option style=\"background-color:#FFCC99\" disabled>".$cat_name."
            </option>"; 

    $categories = db_select_categories($id_cat);
    if(is_array($categories))
    {
     foreach($categories as $row)
      {
    $id = htmlentities($row['id_cat'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $name = htmlentities($row['cat_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
    $name = stripslashes($name);        
    if ( $cat == $id )
    {
    echo "<option value='".$id."'selected> ".$name."</option>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<option value=".$id."> ".$name."</option>";
    }   
    }
    }
    }
    }
    echo "</SELECT>";

    ?>


    <div>
    <?php
    if(!empty($cat))      
    {
    //Outputs a populated select option depending on category 
    display_search_options($cat);
    }   
    ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please fix your tabbing.

Comment: You will have to use AJAX in order to do an asynchronous form submit. Then handle the response of that call. This is the only way to not refresh the entire page.

Comment: I was suggested to use AJAX, but never touched AJAX before. Any links you can point me to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want it to go to form, just make it go somewhere else...

```
 onChange="javascript:this.form.action='index.php'; 
        this.form.submit()
```

Comment: I thought about that, but I have few more files that have the same header. So, it won't work

Comment: Use a variable to know where you are... Maybe $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']